# Bibliography with sentence style respecting grammar of various languages

Tags: biblatex, biber, languages

I'm writing a report in English citing many articles in various other languages (e.g. Italian, Swedish, Norwegian...)

However, even though I added the `autolang=hyphen` option to `biblatex` and added the `langid` option to every non-english article, `biber` or `LaTeX` are still not getting my bibliography to format correctly.

What I want: That the **sentence style in the bibliography respects the language's capitalization rules**. So, e.g. in German, many words are usually capitalized. The title by Loew should therefore read (following sentence style): *Anfänge epiphytischer Lebensweise bei Gefäßplanzen Norddeutschlands*. Every reference should be set for the given language (given by `langid`).

Also, I would like **biblatex' sentence style to ignore the journal title**. It says in the biblatex manual that `titlecase` is set for both `title` and `journaltitle` (however i.e. the book `series` title is still capitalized). So far, I couldn't find a way around but I would prefer the `title` to be *sentence style* and the `journaltitle` to be *capitalized*.

*Secondary Issue:*

Maybe someone can explain me, why the italicization of *Polypodium vulgare* in Johnson's Article is set to all-caps?

I'm using `biber` and `pdflatex` with a customized bibliography style (not given here) based on `authoryear`. (Usually, I also use `babel`, `fontenc` and `lmodern`, but they were not necessary for the MWE)

EDIT: If I wanted to show the compiled document, would I need to upload it or is there a way to do it on `stackexchange`?

Thank you all kind people!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{current.bib}
    @Article{Johnson1921,
        author          = {Johnson, Duncan S.},
        title           = {{\textit{Polypodium vulgare}} as an Epiphyte},
        volume          = {72},
        number          = {4},
        pages           = {237--244},
        date            = {1921},
        groups          = {Accidental Epiphytes},
        journaltitle    = {The University of Chicago Press},
    }
    @Book{Magnin1895,
        author    = {Magnin, A.},
        title     = {Florule adventive des Saules T{\^e}tards de la r{\'e}gion Lyonnnaise},
        publisher = {Librairie G{\'e}n{\'e}rale Henri Georg},
        year      = {1895},
        groups    = {Accidental Epiphytes},
        langid    = {french},
    }
    @Article{Steenis1925,
        author       = {van Steenis, C. G. G. J.},
        title        = {Over de phanerogamen en vaatkryptogamen voorkomende op knotwilgen in Nederland},
        pages        = {360--406},
        date         = {1925},
        journaltitle = {Nederlandse Kruidk. Arch.},
        langid       = {dutch},
    }
    @Article{Staeger1908,
        author          = {St{\"{a}}ger, Rob},
        title           = {Beitrag zur schweizerischen ``Epiphytenflora''},
        pages           = {17--90},
        date            = {1908},
        journaltitle    = {Mittheilungen der Naturforschenden Gesellschaft in Bern},
        langid       = {ngerman},
    }
    @Article{Loew1892,
        author          = {Loew, E.},
        title           = {Anf{\"{a}}nge epiphytischer Lebensweise bei Gef{\"{a}\ss}plfanzen Norddeutschlands},
        volume          = {33},
        pages           = {63--74},
        date            = {1892},
        journaltitle    = {Verhandlungen des Botanischen Vereins f{\"{u}}r die Provinz},
        langid          = {ngerman},
    }
    @Book{Schimper1888,
        title     = {Die epiphytische Vegetation Amerikas},
        publisher = {Universit{\"{a}}t Bonn},
        author    = {Schimper, A. F. W.},
        volume    = {2},
        series    = {Botanische Mittheilungen aus den Tropen},
        booktitle = {Botanische Mittheilungen aus den Tropen},
        date      = {1888},
        langid    = {ngerman},
        location  = {Jena},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,uniquename=init,autolang=hyphen,block=space,style=authoryear,useprefix=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
\bibliography{current}

\begin{document}


\section*{Epiphytes are awesome!}
So this is my main document in English but citing from many sources of various languages \parencite[eg.][]{Steenis1925, Magnin1895, Johnson1921, Staeger1908, Loew1892, Schimper1888}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the starred version of `\MakeSentenceCase`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
```

From the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), pp. 211-212, (emphasis mine)

> [`\MakeSentenceCase`/`\MakeSentenceCase*`] The starred variant differs from the regular version in that it considers the language of the entry, as specified in the `langid` field. If the `langid` field is defined and holds a language declared with `\DeclareCaseLangs` [...],
>   then the sentence case conversion is performed. If the `langid` field is undefined, then the language list declared with `\DeclareCaseLangs` is checked for the presence of the main document language derived from the language option. If found, sentence case conversion is performed, if not, the `text`
>   is not altered in any way. *It is recommended to use `\MakeSentenceCase*` rather than the regular variant in formatting directives.*

By default `journal(title)` is capitalised with `titlecase` as well, if you want to disable that, use

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[default]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[default]{journalsubtitle}}}}
```

To avoid *Polypodium vulgare* being capitalised use

```
title = {\textit{Polypodium vulgare} as an Epiphyte},
```

The issue here was that `biblatex` needs to capitalise the first letter of the title. Because of the braces `biblatex` treated the entire `\textit{Polypodium vulgare}` as the first letter of the sentence and capitalised it, resulting in shouting.